# Does the messiah have no share in God?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

The סידור תהלת ה׳ is widely used by Chabad-Lubavitch people and synagogues everywhere. It is, if anything is, the official prayer book of Chabad-Lubavitch. Here's what it has to say (immediately after the weekday morning שמונה עשרה):

> כל המשיח בבהכ״נ בשעה שהצבור עסוקין בשבחו של מקום מראה בעצמו שאין לו חלק באלקי ישראל
>
> Any messiah in the synagogue, while the community is busy praising the place, shows about himself that he has no share in the God of Israel.

I don't fully understand this passage, but I'm worried. Because every Chabad-Lubavitch synagogue I've been to has a messiah in the synagogue. A big portrait, usually right near the entrance, usually that pose with his hand up.

So, like I said, I don't really understand the passage — what does praising the synagogue have to do with anything? But it *sounds like* it's saying the messiah shows that he has no share in God, which I find hard to swallow. Or maybe the guy who put up the picture has no share in God? Can someone please clarify this passage? This has been bothering me quite a bit.

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: is every habad synagogue messianic? am i missing something?

Comment: @mevaqesh, it's [tag:purim-torah-in-jest]. Also, note that I didn't say the synagogue is messianic: rather, **I** was referring to him as the messiah.